# node-gyp build gives unresolved external symbol error

Tags: c++, node.js, msbuild, swig, node-gyp

I'm trying to access c++ code form javascript and for which I used [swig](http://swig.org/).  Now when i try to run the command `node-gyp configure build` I got the below errors.  Can anyone help me here and tell why this is happening

```
C:\Users\UAL\Desktop\DeskoPenta\Code\SwigWithDeskoCode>node-gyp configure build

gyp info it worked if it ends with okQA

gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0

gyp info using node@10.14.2 | win32 | x64

gyp info spawn C:\Users\UAL\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe

gyp info spawn args [ 'C:\\Users\\UAL\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',

gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',

gyp info spawn args   '-f',

gyp info spawn args   'msvs',

gyp info spawn args   '-G',

gyp info spawn args   'msvs_version=2015',

gyp info spawn args   '-I',

gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\UAL\\Desktop\\DeskoPenta\\Code\\SwigWithDeskoCode\\build\\config.gypi',

gyp info spawn args   '-I',

gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\UAL\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',

gyp info spawn args   '-I',

gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\UAL\\.node-gyp\\10.14.2\\include\\node\\common.gypi',

gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',

gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',

gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\UAL\\.node-gyp\\10.14.2',

gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Users\\UAL\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp',

gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\Users\\UAL\\.node-gyp\\10.14.2\\<(target_arch)\\node.lib',

gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\Users\\UAL\\Desktop\\DeskoPenta\\Code\\SwigWithDeskoCode',

gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',

gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',

gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',

gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',

gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\UAL\\Desktop\\DeskoPenta\\Code\\SwigWithDeskoCode\\build',

gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]

gyp info spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe

gyp info spawn args [ 'build/binding.sln',

gyp info spawn args   '/clp:Verbosity=minimal',

gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',

gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64' ]

Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
     Creating library C:\Users\UAL\Desktop\DeskoPenta\Code\SwigWithDeskoCode\build\Release\example.lib and object C:\Us
  ers\UAL\Desktop\DeskoPenta\Code\SwigWithDeskoCode\build\Release\example.exp
example.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_DMRZGetDocType [C:\Users\UAL\Desktop\DeskoPenta\Code\Swig
WithDeskoCode\build\example.vcxproj]
example.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_DMRZGetField [C:\Users\UAL\Desktop\DeskoPenta\Code\SwigWi
thDeskoCode\build\example.vcxproj]
example.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_DMRZDestroyHandle [C:\Users\UAL\Desktop\DeskoPenta\Code\S
wigWithDeskoCode\build\example.vcxproj]
example.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_DMRZCreateMrzDescriptor [C:\Users\UAL\Desktop\DeskoPenta\
Code\SwigWithDeskoCode\build\example.vcxproj]
example.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_DMRZValidateAllChecksums [C:\Users\UAL\Desktop\DeskoPenta
\Code\SwigWithDeskoCode\build\example.vcxproj]
example.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_DMRZParseMrz [C:\Users\UAL\Desktop\DeskoPenta\Code\SwigWi
thDeskoCode\build\example.vcxproj]
example.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ConnectToDevice [C:\Users\UAL\Desktop\DeskoPenta\Code\Swi
gWithDeskoCode\build\example.vcxproj]
example.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_PrepareBmpClippedDocumentImage [C:\Users\UAL\Desktop\Desk
oPenta\Code\SwigWithDeskoCode\build\example.vcxproj]
example.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetPropertyString [C:\Users\UAL\Desktop\DeskoPenta\Code\S
wigWithDeskoCode\build\example.vcxproj]
example.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_SetupOnDevicePlugCallback [C:\Users\UAL\Desktop\DeskoPent
a\Code\SwigWithDeskoCode\build\example.vcxproj]
example.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetMsrOutput [C:\Users\UAL\Desktop\DeskoPenta\Code\SwigWi
thDeskoCode\build\example.vcxproj]
example.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_SetupOnOcrCallback [C:\Users\UAL\Desktop\DeskoPenta\Code\
SwigWithDeskoCode\build\example.vcxproj]
example.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_UseBuzzer [C:\Users\UAL\Desktop\DeskoPenta\Code\SwigWithD
eskoCode\build\example.vcxproj]
example_wrap.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetBuzzerSettings2 [C:\Users\UAL\Desktop\DeskoPenta\
Code\SwigWithDeskoCode\build\example.vcxproj]
C:\Users\UAL\Desktop\DeskoPenta\Code\SwigWithDeskoCode\build\Release\example.node : fatal error LNK1120: 134 unresolved
 externals [C:\Users\UAL\Desktop\DeskoPenta\Code\SwigWithDeskoCode\build\example.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error

gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1

gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\UAL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:262:23)

gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)

gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:12)

gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134

gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\UAL\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "build"

gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\UAL\Desktop\DeskoPenta\Code\SwigWithDeskoCode

gyp ERR! node -v v10.14.2

gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0

gyp ERR! not ok
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GYP is a meta-build system that generates files for various build systems, MSBuild, in your case. In your case, error occurs later at MSBuild level, not node-gyp level.

You are using certain headers where all these functions are defined, but not linking against the corresponding `*.lib` library or `*.c`/`.cpp` sources.

Your library seems to be a proprietary library related to document scanning devices.

You can link against this missing library by using `libraries` section of the GYP file:

```
'libraries': ['mylibrary.lib']
```

And then rebuild MSBuild files:

```
node-gyp configure
```

Comment: Apreciate your reply, but I'm still not able to fix it.  Here is my binding.gyp file
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "example",
      "sources": [ "example.cxx", "example_wrap.cxx" ],
      'libraries': ['PageScanAPI.lib', 'deskomrz.lib']
    }
  ]
}

Comment: @VinodhKumarC Probably you also need `library_dirs` section and look for errors again. I recommend to begin with a working `binding.gyp` file. For example, see my [GYP file for a CUDA binding module](https://gist.github.com/o2genum/f26c4bf526bf455ad9e1f32fbd3b9d04). Or check out some native npm modules that have `binding.gyp` files.

Comment: Changing my gyp file as below and keeping all the dll and lib file inside my root folder solved my issue
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "example",
      "sources": [ "example.cxx", "example_wrap.cxx" ],
      "libraries": [ "<(module_root_dir)/PageScanAPI","<(module_root_dir)/deskomrz" ]
    }
      ]
}